# $(p \wedge q) \wedge p$ convert to CNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was doing some exercises to convert formulas to CNF by means of the axioms and I imagined the following exercise $(p \wedge q) \wedge p$, but for this exercise, I do not find an axiom that can take me to CNF. However, I know that if I use the truth table I could solve it. I would like to know if there is an axiom that I may not know, by which you can work the exercise.

Comment: Is your expression already in CNF?  If not, why not?

Comment: $p \land q$ may be what you want?

Comment: it must be a conjunction of disjunctions so that it is  CNF, no?

Comment: $p$ is a disjunct of one literal.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}(p\wedge q)\wedge p &= p\wedge(p\wedge q) &&\text{commutivity}\\ &= (p\wedge p)\wedge q &&\text{associativity}\\ &=p\wedge q && \text{idempotence}\end{align}$

Comment: I had not thought about it that way, thank you. And what if I had (p∧q) ∧ (p∧q)?

Comment: Idempotence again: $(p\wedge q)\wedge (p\wedge q)=(p\wedge q)$.

Answer (score 0):

$ (p \land q) \land p$ is already in CNF ...

And if you don't like the parentheses there, then please know that CNF is define as a *generalized* conjunction of generalised disjunctions of literals.

As such, $(p \land q) \land p$ may be better put simply as $p \land q \land p$ ... which can of course be simplified to $p \land q$, but does not need to be to count as being in CNF

Also, if you are wondering where the disjunctions are ... $p$ is a disjunction consisting of exactly one disjunct, and that disjunct is a literal $p$. Thus, $p \land q \land p$ is a conjunction of three conjuncts, where each conjunct is a disjunction of exactly one disjunct, and where each disjunct is a literal, and so again, yes, it is in CNF

Comment: Explain to me because, it is not supposed to be a conjunction of disjunctions. (p ∧ q) would not be a problem? This exercise would be a disjunction of disjunctions on the left.

Comment: @pete it is $p \land q \land p$, so it is a conjunction with three conjuncts, where each of the conjuncts is a disjunction with exactly one disjunct.

Comment: As I understand then (p∧q) ∧ (p∧q) this would be equivalent to p∧q∧p∧q and if I delete repeated literals I would be left with nothing?

Comment: @pete $(p \land q) \land (p \land q)$ is indeed $p \land q \land p \land q$. You can remove copies, yes, but you have to leave at least one original, so you can simplify to $p \land q$

Comment: Of course, you're right is lost is when it's a literal and its opposite ¬p∧p, right?